# How did Jim and Alfred know that the guards weren't real?

Tags: plot-explanation, gotham

In *Gotham* S04E05, when Bruce is taken captive by Ra's Al Ghul in the prison, Jim and Alfred visit the prison. While they are being toured around the facility by one of the guards, they realize that they aren't real guards but men working for Ra's.

What gave it away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the could not know for sure, but they had three clues:

1) Gordon had been in Blackgate as a prisoner, but he never saw the first guard:

> **Gordon:** How long have you worked here?
>
> **Fake guard 1:** Two years, thereabouts.
>
> **Gordon:** I was in Blackgate for a time.
>
> **Fake guard 1:** We must not have overlapped. Here? As a guard?
>
> **Gordon:** As a prisoner.
>
> **Fake guard 1:** Oh, yeah. Heard about that.

2) The guards did not go throw maximum security section (something which maybe was custom, as Gordon knows the place...) and gave a cheap excuse for that:

> **Gordon:** Is there a reason why you're not taking us through maximum security?
>
> **Fake guard 1:** Prisoners are in the yard this time of day. Been some changes since you were here.

3) Gordon read the name tag "McCloskey" on a guard uniform, but the guard was not the McCloskey he knows:

> **Gordon**: "McCloskey." That's funny. I know another J. McCloskey who works here.
>
> **Fake guard 2:** My cousin. Gets confusing sometimes.